# Using placeholders/variables in a sed command

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I want to store a specific part of a matched result as a variable to be used for replacement later. I would like to keep this in a one liner instead of finding the variable I need before hand.

when configuring apache, and use mod_rewrite, you can specificy specific parts of patterns to be used as variables,like this:

```
RewriteRule ^www.example.com/page/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/page.php?page=$1 [R=301,L]
```

the part of the pattern match that's contained inside the parenthesis is stored as $1 for use later. So if the url was `www.example.com/page/home`, it would be replaced with `www.example.com/page.php?page=home`. So the "home" part of the match was saved in $1 because it was the part of the pattern inside the parenthesis.

I want something like this functionality with a `sed` command, I need to automatically replace many strings in a SQL dump file, to add drop table if exist commands before each create table, but I need to know the table name to do this, so if the dump file contains something like:

```
...
CREATE TABLE `orders`
...
```

I need to run something like:

```
cat dump.sql | sed "s/CREATE TABLE `(.*)`/DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $1\N CREATE TABLE `$1`/g"
```

to get the result of:

```
...
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `orders`
CREATE TABLE `orders`
...
```

I'm using the mod_rewrite syntax in the `sed` command as a logical example of what I'm trying to do.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
sed '/CREATE TABLE \([^ ]*\)/ s//DROP TABLE IF EXISTS \1; &/'
```

Find a CREATE TABLE statement and capture the table name.  Replace it with 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS' and the table name, plus a semi-colon to terminate the statement, and a copy of what was matched to preserve the CREATE TABLE statement.

This is classic `sed` notation.  Since you're using `bash`, there's a chance you're using GNU `sed` and will need to add `--posix` to use that notation, or you'll need to fettle the script to use GNU's non-standard `sed` regexes.  I've also not attempted to insert a newline into the output.  You can do that with GNU `sed` if it is important enough to you.

The key points are the parentheses (classically needing to be escaped with a backslash) are the capture mechanism, and backslash-number is the replacement mechanism.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation, it has completely answered my question.

Answer (score 6):

```
 sed -r "s/CREATE TABLE (\`.*\`)/DROP TABLE IF EXISTS \1\n &/g" dump.sql
```

**test**:

```
kent$  cat t.txt

CREATE TABLE `orders`
...

CREATE TABLE `foo`
...
...

CREATE TABLE `bar`
...


kent$  sed -r "s/CREATE TABLE (\`.*\`)/DROP TABLE IF EXISTS \1\n &/g" t.txt

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `orders`
 CREATE TABLE `orders`
...

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `foo`
 CREATE TABLE `foo`
...
...

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `bar`
 CREATE TABLE `bar`
...
```

Answer (score 5):

This is called a "back reference". And sed will start numbering the things between the parenthesis. \(...\)

Note the use of backslash as an escape character above.

Ref: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer to the OP's question via title of this thread:
As @bhoom-suktitipat states: This is called a "back reference"...

SUMMARY:
Placeholder variables, or back reference lookup is achieved, on the replace side, by using backslash followed by a digit, starting at 1, like so: `\1`

BACKGROUND: I'm here because I've been taking a bunch of code and revamping it. In the process I want to pre-eslint it to find all the double quotes around JSON keys and strip them. [ESLint's Quote Props Rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/quote-props) can be used, with --fix, to do the exact opposite of what I need todo.

MISSION OUTLINE:

Turn
`{ "foo": "bar" }`
into `{ foo: "bar" }`, a.k.a. **using-placeholders-variables-in-a-sed-command**

1. Find the equivalent of the "foo" (key) in the second matching group: `("{1})(\w+)(":{1})`.
2. Use that matching group as a placeholder to render `foo:`, instead of `"foo":`
3. Write changes to file.

*Write to different file:*

`sed -r 's/("{1})(\w+)(":{1})/\2:/g' in.js > out.js`

*Write to same file:*

`sed -ri 's/("{1})(\w+)(":{1})/\2:/g' in-and-out.js`

SED flags used:

`-E, -r, --regexp-extended
                 use extended regular expressions in the script
                 (for portability use POSIX -E).`

`-i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
                 edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)`